# Objective-C: copying a returned NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am calling a method getHoleScore that populates a NSMutableArray and returns it. I'm trying to copy the array so that the calling method can access the items but I get this exception every time:

exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

I've tried multiple different ways of copying an array that I've found on this site but nothing seems to work. Here's the code:

```
Score *theScore = self.roundScore;
NSMutableArray *scores = [[[self delegate]getHoleScore:self score:theScore] mutableCopy];
NSInteger total = 0;

if (theScore) {
    self.playerName.text = theScore.name;
    self.courseName.text = theScore.course;
    self.hole1Field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[scores objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]];
    self.hole2Field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[scores objectAtIndex:1] integerValue]];
    self.hole3Field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[scores objectAtIndex:2] integerValue]];
    self.hole4Field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[scores objectAtIndex:3] integerValue]];
    self.hole5Field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[scores objectAtIndex:4] integerValue]];
```

etc.

Any idea on how to populate the scores array?

Comment: What happens if you call `NSLog(@"%@", scores);` right after that `NSMutableArray *scores` declaration?

Comment: I just get an open parentheses followed by the same exception.

Comment: On which line do you get this exception? Can you show us getHoleScore definition?

Comment: Are you sure that `[[self delegate] getHoleScore:self score:theScore]` returns a non-nil result?

Comment: Please add the code for `getHoleScore:score`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reaching 0 for your mutable array because it hasn't been alloc/init yet. you either have to place this `NSMutableArray *myscores = [NSMutableArray array];` above you [[self delegate] ] call.

Or a better way to do this would be creating your myscores and pass the method in with a this built in nsarray super class method, which takes care of alloc/init your array.

`NSMutableArray *myscores = 
   [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self delegate] getHoleScore:self 
                                                         score:theScore];`

also make sure that
 `[[self delegate]getHoleScore:self  score:theScore]`is not sending you a empty array, calling a -objectAtIndex:a on a empty array will crash your code. A good way to check if your array is empty or not is calling the method -count method on your array, calling count on a array won't crash your code, even if it's zero.

Comment: hm, no. The array is properly alloced/inited (via `-mutableCopy`). It's just that the array is likely empty (has no element) so accessing `objectAtIndex:0` is out of the array's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the help everyone. You were right that getHoleScore returned something nil. It was working off an sqlite database but once I cleared it and then re-added the data, everything worked fine.